# Flume HTTPSource refuses JSON body due to malform

Tags: python, json, urllib2, flume, flume-ng

I have a Flume agent configuration where I use an HTTPSource to recieve event data from specific services. For testing purposes, I am creating the static JSON structure as a string object, named data, in Python (see code snippet 1 below) and sending the object to flume wih proper header but then flume returns me a 400-bad request error all the time (see snippet 2 below). The associated flume execution exception message has been provided in snippet 3 below.

**Question:** Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my static json request that causes flume HTTPSource to refuse it? Is there some other problem I might be missing, which is irrelevant to the json data? Thanks.

**SNIPPET 1 (Python script generating the dummy HTTP request containing my static JSON data)**

```
 import urllib2, json

 serviceName = "serviceA"
 timestamp = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

 body = "{ \"service\":\"" + serviceName + "\" }"
 print("BODY: " +  body)

 //My JSON data
 data = "[{ \"headers\" : { \"timestamp\" : \"" + timestamp + "\" }, \"body\" : " + body + " }]"
 print("DATA: "  + data)

 req = urllib2.Request("http://10.1.0.100:5140")
 req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)
```

**SNIPPET 2 - Execution Output of the python script**

```
  BODY: { "service":"serviceA" }
  DATA: [{ "headers" : { "timestamp" : "2016-01-13 12:26:48" }, "body" : { "service":"serviceA" } }]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./event_data_gen.py", line 57, in <module>
  response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request from client. 
  Request has invalid JSON Syntax.
```

**SNIPPET 3 - Exception message in Flume's execution output**

```
  2016-01-13 12:26:48,653 (34313572@qtp-604003190-13)
  [WARN -     org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:      242)] Received bad request from client. 
  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPBadRequestException: Request has invalid JSON Syntax.
  at org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler.getEvents(JSONHandler.java:119)
  at  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:240)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
  Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line  1 column 67
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
  at org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler.getEvents(JSONHandler.java:117)
... 17 more
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was  BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 67
  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:464)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:349)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:337)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
```

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with the python script nor the data. Valid json statements are not accepted by flume somehow. It bothers about the usage of double quota in the body statement of the json request even if the entire json strcuture is valid. Strange that the flume user guide does not touch this at all.

Follwoing valid JSON request is not accepted by flume for example:

[{ "headers" : { "timestamp" : "2016-01-13 15:21:31" }, "body" : { "from":"device1", "user":"Mehmet", "vendor":"TELIA", "service":"serviceA", "function":"scale-out", "description":"REASON TEXT 1 " } }]

Comment: Which is your configuration? Just in order to know which handler are you using in your Http source.

Comment: It is jsonhandler...

Comment: I think the `body` is supposed to be a string, not a JSON object. For example, this request works fine:

``curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d ' [{ "headers" : { "timestamp" : "2016-01-13 15:21:31", "from":"device1", "user":"Mehmet", "vendor":"TELIA", "service":"serviceA", "function":"scale-out", "description":"REASON TEXT 1 "}, "body":"This is the body text" }] ' http://localhost:9090``

Answer (score 0):

As @Martyn W indicated in his comment, the JSONHandler expects and validates that the JSON has a certain structure.

This is described in the [JavaDocs of JSONHandler](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/flume-ng/apidocs/org/apache/flume/source/http/JSONHandler.html):

> JSONHandler for HTTPSource that accepts an array of events. This
> handler throws exception if the deserialization fails because of bad
> format or any other reason. Each event must be encoded as a map with
> two key-value pairs.
>
> 1. headers - the key for this key-value pair is "headers". The value for this key is another map, which represent the event headers. These
>    headers are inserted into the Flume event as is.
> 2. body - The body is a string which represents the body of the event. The key for this key-value pair is "body". All key-value pairs are
>    considered to be headers. An example:
>
> [{"headers" : {"a":"b", "c":"d"},"body": "random_body"}, {"headers" :
> {"e": "f"},"body": "random_body2"}]